# Concept of table relations in Laravel

Tags: php, function, laravel, relationship

I have two tables:

- `Cards`
- `Notes`

Each *Card* has multiple *Notes*. So there is a relation between them like this:

```
class Card extends Model {

    public function notes ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }
}
```

Ok well, all fine.

---

Now I need to understand the concept of these two lines:

```
$card()->$notes()->first();
```

and

```
$card()->$notes->first();
```

What's the difference between them? As you see in the first one `$note()` is a function and in the second one `$note` isn't a function. How will they be translated in PHP?

The first one points out to the `card` table and the second one points out to the `notes` table, right? or what? Anyway I've stuck to understand the concept of tham.

Comment: `$notes()` is the method whereas `$notes` is the property of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about `$` before the `$notes` in your code but if you trying to say something like this.

```
1- $card->notes()->first();
2- $card->notes->first();
```

In the code in line 1, first you have a `$card` model and then you wanted to access all `notes()` related to that `$card`, and because of adding `()` after `notes` you simply call `query builder` on notes, show you can perform any other database query function after that, something like `where, orderBy, groupBy, ...` and any other complicated query on database.

But in the second one you actually get access to a `collection` of notes related to that `$card`, we can say that you get **all related notes** from database and set it into laravel collections and you are no more able to perform database query on `notes`.

> Note: because laravel collections have some methods like `where(), groupBy(), whereIn(), sort(), ...` you can use them on the second one, but in that case you perform those methods on **collections and not database**, `you already get all results from database`